# Hide table header if no records present in the remarks column - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I hide the table header, such as Remark, with a method when no records exists in remark attribute column?

index.html.erb:

```
<table>
    <% has_remark = collection_has_remark?(@aslani361s) %>
        <thead>
            <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Discount</td>
                    <td>Paid</td>
                    <td>Balance</td>
                    <td>DelnDel</td>
                    <% if has_remark %>
                    <td>Remark</td>
                    <% end %>
                    <td>Hide</td>
                </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

_aslani361.html.erb:

```
<% if aslani361.remark.present? -%>
    <td class="col-1"><%= aslani361.remark %></td>
<% end %>
```

aslani361s_helper.rb:

```
module Aslani361sHelper
    def collection_has_remark?(collection)
        collection.each do |aslani361|
            if aslani361.remark.present?
                return true
            end
        end
    end
end
```

[image: screeshot.png]

The problem is I am not able to hide the **Remark** table header but I can hide the records.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to hide the `header`. what if some records has `remark` and some doesn't which is a general case. So, keeping that in mind let the header be there even if you don't have remark on any record in my opinion. Think from the UX prospective, your user will never realize that a `remark` column does exists until there is a `remark` if you hide that header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your point.In future, if I need to do the same for anything else it will be more helpful to me.

Comment: Hey I think you should be able to just check for the presence of remark on all the records and let say if none has it then remove header. which you have already tried but there is an issue in your condition, you are returning `true` on every check instead set it to `true` and break out of the loop the minute you find a remark present on any record.

Comment: I would also try something like `any?` on this collection to check if `remark` is true on any of the record. for ex: `a = [0, 1, 2]` then I'll check if item `1` is present or not by writing `a.any? { |x| x.eql?(1) }`. may be you can try similar way to figure out the presence.

Comment: Thanks again, I can hide records but can't hide header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `collection_has_remark?` will return `true` if there's `aslani361.remark`, and the `collection` itself if there is no (the return value of `each`), both of which evaluate as 'truthy' values for conditions.

Use:

```
def collection_has_remark?(collection)
    collection.each do |aslani361|
        if aslani361.remark.present?
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

or better:

```
def collection_has_remark?(collection)
    collection.any?{|aslani361| aslani361.remark.present?}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Now I am able to hide the Remark Column but when some records is present then it becomes somewhat distorting, you can see in the above image.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen that is because you check every item in view, but you need to check collection and if any item has the field - output the `td` for all, empty for those without the field

Comment: Thanks again.I got your point but where and what do I need to modify the code.Please guide...

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen pass `has_remark` variable to `_aslani361.html.erb` parial and check it instead of `aslani361.remark.present?`

Comment: Excellent! It is working perfect.Thank you very much.How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191943/getting-duplicate-records-when-returning-search-results-with-ajax-rails